# AD password for LDAP users

Tags: active-directory, openldap, single-sign-on, slapd

My company has a central Active directory server and our team has its own OpenLDAP server for managing infrastructure.  I would like to use the same password for our ldap users as the password in AD.  How can I pass requests for certain attributes onto the AD server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a previous employer, they tried to disable changing passwords via control-alt-delete and force password changing via a web page to address this particular issue.

Sadly, you'll likely have to either invest in a third party product or write something (like the web page mentioned above) in order to sync the passwords.

Comment: my other idea was to use a script to query and pull the password attribute from AD and modify the corresponding attribute in our ldap directory.